# int.Parse not throwing an exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have a custom control that contains a TextBox. The custom class has 3 properties, MinValue, MaxValue, and Value, defined as so:

```
public int Value
{
    get { return int.Parse(text.Text); }
    set
    {
        text.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}

public int MaxValue { get; set; }
public int MinValue { get; set; }
```

When the TextBox inside the custom class loses focus, the following method is run:

```
void text_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Value = Value > MaxValue ? MaxValue : Value;
    Value = Value < MinValue ? MinValue : Value;
}
```

If the TextBox has a string that is larger than 2,147,483,647, the text stays the same when focus is lost, and no exception is thrown.

Why is the exception not thrown, and how can I make it so it will also set  values higher than `Int32.MaxValue` to `MaxValue`, and values lower than `Int32.MinValue` to `MinValue`?

Comment: Where do you expect to catch the Exception?

Comment: It crashes like a ton of bricks when I tries this, you have to be hiding a try/catch somewhere.  The approach is very wrong, LostFocus is a very dangerous event that is hidden in the designer in purpose.  Use the Validating event instead and use int.TryParse().  And be sure to deal with no text having been entered yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so I found the issue:

[image]

The checkbox inside the red circle unchecked itself. Could've been when I repaired the installation of my IDE (VS Express 2012). I recently installed VS 2012 Professional and they use the same options because checking it in Professional also fixed it in Express

Answer (score 1):

First, there a are different integer data types in C#.

e.g.

`Int32` with a range from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

`Int64` with a range from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

It's technical not possible to have a greater range using an `Int32` as it uses 32bits of memory. 
Using an unsigned version of the type will shift the range to only positive values, so if you don't need negative values, you could also take a look at an `UInt32`.
**To actual increase the range, your only option is, using an `Int64` data type.**

see also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/exx3b86w.aspx

(`int` is an alias for `Int32`, `long` for `Int64`)

Second, as you neither have a `try-catch` block nor using `TryParse` there should be an unhandled `System.OverflowException`. If there's no exception at all, that's somehow strange. Are you sure, that's not inside a `try-catch` block?

**Anyway I would recommend to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` and handle errors accordingly.**

Comment: The question is "why is the exception not thrown". This does not seem to answer that question.

Comment: Srsly? Read the question, and you will see that he is asking more than just this question.. My answer is going into the main two issues he has "how to set a higher value than Int32.MaxValue" and "why there's no exception", ok for the second one maybe its not a 100% sure answer, but at least I tried to give him a clue about what may went wrong and how he should implement it "using TryParse and handling the error when it fails". So I really don't get your problem, with my answer.

Comment: Given what little code was shown, it's just as likely `Int32.MaxValue` is a typo, or at best a poorly explained element of the question...the code clearly is simply trying to constrain values to within the `MaxValue` and `MinValue` properties, not the entire range of `int`, and I find code more reliably expressive than descriptive text. Bottom line: it's _my perception_ that this doesn't do anything to answer the actual question. Let me know if the OP accepts your answer, and I'll happily retract my comment, complete with an apology for my mistake.

Comment: Thx for the detailed feedback. Maybe I just have a different understanding of the question than your have, we'll see. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your situation, and wanted to understand what was going on, I would run the app under the debugger, with a breakpoint in the `LostFocus` event handler.  You could also consider adding a try/catch/throw, which might make it easier verify that an exception is indeed being thrown, and if so to inspect it before it is swallowed:

```
void text_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Value = Value > MaxValue ? MaxValue : Value;
        Value = Value < MinValue ? MinValue : Value;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a comment masquerading as an answer

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Actually it's meant to be an answer - teach a man to fish and all that.